# Calling class function saved as attribute

Tags: python, function, class, attributes

I have two classes and a "use" class function that performs multiple actions using the various attributes as the inputs so that I can just call the one function and get different results based on which class object is referenced. Where I am getting stuck is that I want to have part of the use function check the 'effect' attribute and call the function found there. Currently, the function named in effect is called when the object c is defined, and everything I have tried within the use function has no effect or returns 'none' since I don't have a return statement in the add and sub functions.
I've provided a simplified example code below. C has 9 attributes and 10 different class functions that I would want to use in the effect spot. I plan on having 50+ different C objects, so not having to write out specific functions for each one would be spectacular.

In this example, the print(p.h) at the end returns 101, showing that designing the C object calls the add function I put in the attribute:

```
M= []
class P:
    def __init__(p, h, s):
        p.h= h
        p.s=s
class C:
    def __init__(y, name, d, f effect,):
        y.name= name
        y.effect= effect
        y.d= d
        y.f= f
    
    def use(c):
        M.append(c)
        p.h -= p. y.d
        p.s += y.f
        effect
    def add(c, x):
        p.h += x
    def sub(c, x):
        p.h -=x
p= P(100)   
c= C('test1', add(1), 1)
print(p.h)
```

I have tried the add and sub functions as both class and standalone, which didn't seem to make a difference, calling y.effect as though it were a function which just returns 'none' as mentioned, and adding the property decorator, which threw an error, probably because I don't quite understand what that is supposed to do yet.

Comment: Please provide real (runnable) code -- and I suggest always using `self` as the name for the "self" argument in methods so you don't confuse yourself or others.  This code uses different things like `y` and `c` and `p` and doesn't use them consistently within the same function, which makes the code unrunnable as well as making it very hard to figure out what you were trying to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing methods of classes `C` and `P`, you will only be able to access them from the class namespace. `C.add` will work, but `add` will not.

Furthermore if you call `c.add(4)` it will be the same thing as calling `C.add(c, 4)` because it will implicitly pass the **instance** `c` into the **class** (`C`) method `C.add`. You cannot call `add(1)` or `c.add(1)` before your instance `c` is initialized by the `__init__` method.

Typically when writing python, it is most clear to always name the first argument to your class method `self` to make it clear that `self` refers to the instance and that it will automatically get passed into the function.

Furthermore, because you do not instantiate `p` until after you define your class `C`, you won't be able to access `p` from inside your C class unless you pass `p` into the function or save it as an attribute of `c`.

Not totally sure what you are going for here but I made some modifications which might help.

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python
M = []


class P:
    def __init__(self, h, s):
        # self refers to your instance of p
        self.h = h
        self.s = s


class C:
    def __init__(self, name, p, d, f, effect):
        # self refers to your instance of c
        self.p = p  # save an instance of p as an attribute of your instance of c
        self.name = name
        self.effect = effect
        self.d = d
        self.f = f

    def use(self):
        M.append(self)
        self.p.h -= self.d
        self.p.s += self.f
        return self.effect

    def add(self, x):
        # self refers to your instance of c and gets implicitly passed in as the first argument
        # when c.add(2) is called
        self.p.h += x

    def sub(self, x):
        self.p.h -= x


p = P(100, 50)
c = C('test1', p, d=2, f=1, effect="a")
c.add(1)
print(p.h)
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't runnable as-is, so there may be other problems with your real code that aren't possible to discern from this example, but when you say:

> function named in effect is called when the object c is defined

that's happening not because of what's inside your `C` class, but the line where you construct your `C`:

```
c= C('test1', add(1), 1)
```

The expression `add(1)` isn't passing the `add` function, it's *calling* the `add` function and passing its *result*.  To pass a function as an argument, just pass the function itself without the `()`:

```
c = C('test1', add, 1)
```

Note that in the code you provided there is no function called `add` in the current scope, and your `C.use` does not call `effect`, which is a different problem.